# can't add a string element to numpy zeros array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm new to python and numpy and I wanted to create an array with mixed data types but I get this error :

```
>>> m = np.zeros((5,10))
>>> m[0,0] = 'e'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
m[0,0] = 'e'
ValueError: could not convert string to float: e
```

I'm using numpy beacuse it's easier to implement bigger sized arrays and edit them. 
I tried to change the data type of the array but I couldn't find any suitable one.

Comment: there is the `dtype` parameter. See [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at [this part of the numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you really, *really* want an array with mixed data types, use `dtype = object`.

   ```
   m = np.zeros((5,10), dtype = object)

   m[0,0] = 'e'

   m
   Out[105]: 
   array([['e', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)
   ```
2. Now, you probably don't want that really, since object arrays are fairly useless and most `numpy` functions don't work with them.  If you want to import a database into an array, for instance, you will want to use a [Structured Array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).  This will let you mix strings and numbers in such a way that you can still do something with them via `numpy`
3. If you really just want a way to deal with big databases using an efficient indexing scheme, you probably don't want `numpy` at all, but but instead want `pandas` or even `dask`.  `numpy` is optimized for calculation, not storage.

Comment: I tried 'a2' as a type it worked too. I'm just trying to implement maze escaping algorithm and I wanted a "neater" way to represent the map instead of numbers.